# Etherpad server installation

Tags: etherpad

I am trying to deploy an etherpad installation on a linux server. However I am unable to find ways to allow etherpad to save documents onto the server. I want to save the text files that I edit with etherpad to be available as a .txt file in a particular directory on the server.

Any suggestions as to how I can go about doing this? I did not find much documentation online to help me with this, hence resorting to this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question

Comment: how can I put it in the right category?

Comment: look at the official etherpad site and see if they have a discussion forum or mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the txt output of a pad by appending

```
/export/txt
```

to your Etherpad Pad URL

You should read the documentation.